# Pro and Cons of using Clusters of Mac Mini Servers

Tags: serveradmin

As server assembling becoming less of a norm for software engineers, leave Web-based entrepreneurs with 2 choices:

1. Backend as a service: buy a service (e.g., VPS) and deploy a code on some other company's servers.
2. Scale/grow your servers: Just buy servers and scaling them to fulfill the need of your apps.

The first choice is not suitable for me, mainly because of security issues. So I go with the second choice. Therefore, I would like to grow my own servers, but would like to use an Apple-based product. However, Apple does not provide server racks anymore, so I left with using Mac Mini servers. I would like to know is it efficient to solely based a business logic on a cluster of Mac Mini servers?

Comment: Why do you need an Apple-based product? Practically anything you run on a Mac should work on Linux.

Comment: @0942v8653 a Mac Mini server is one of the cheapest server units compare to any other configured units (e.g., racks) sold by other companies (e.g, HP, Dell, etc.), that looks like can scale up easily (e.g., done by Facebook for testing purposes).

Comment: What about an Intel NUC instead of Mac Mini?